# Is there a way to see a textual description of fights?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've seen some pretty descriptive descriptions of fights in Dwarf Fortress.

I always assumed they were from Adventure mode. Is there a way to see a textual description of combats in Fortress mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course there is!

Just press `r` in the main menu to view the combat / hunting / sparring [reports](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Reports).  You'll see a list of report topics, each of which generally describes one side of a fight.  So, for example, if your hunter has cornered a groundhog, you'll see two reports of it, something like:

> - the Hunter Lokum Rosatkeskal is hunting!
> - the Groundhog is fighting!

Select any of the reports and press enter to view all the gory (and I do mean gory) details of the fight.

Answer (score 6):

Pressing <kbd>r</kbd> will bring up Combat **R** eports, which has the blow-by-blow information you're looking for.

<kbd>s</kbd> will bring up **S** parring reports, which are a less violent version of the former.